# OOP implementation of in-memory file system

Tags: javascript, file-system

I was working on this problem, where I am constructing a Object Oriented structure of file system where you can have Directories and Files. The Directories could have sub Directories and files.

I have the following layout and I am looking for feedback on improvements or if my approach is wrong.

My OOP design has three different classes Root, Directory and Files

```
class Root {
    constructor(name, size, writable, parent){
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
        this.writable = writable;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    getName(){
        return this.name;
    };

    setName(val){
        this.name = val;
    }
}

class Directory extends Root{
    constructor(name, size, writable, parent){
        super(name, size, writable, parent);
        this.children = [];
    }

    addContent(obj){
        this.children.push(obj);
    }

    getContent(){
        return this.children;
    }
}

class File extends Root{
    constructor(name, size, writable, parent){
        super(name, size, writable, parent);
    }

    getSize(){
        return this.size;
    }
}


let root = new Root('head', 100, true);
let directory1 = new Directory('sample', 40, true, root);
let file1 = new File('test', 12, true, directory1);
let file2 = new File('test2', 14, true, directory1);
let subDirectory = new Directory('sample2', 40, true, directory1);
directory1.addContent(file1);
directory1.addContent(file2);
directory1.addContent(subDirectory);

console.log(directory1.getContent());
```

Comment: What kind of data will be most commonly stored with this?

Answer (score 3):

I'd say `Root` is a misnomer here, since at first glance I imagined it to represent the filesystem root (i.e. the `/` directory), not the root of your class tree. Moreover, instead of deriving `File` and `Directory` from a common (abstract) ancestor, I'd derive `Directory` from `File` instead, since that's what most real filesystems do anyway, i.e. they treat directories as special files.

`size` should not be a writable property; the `File` object should always calculate it based on its content. This can ensure there's no discrepancy between the stored size and the actual size of the file's content. Also, why doesn't `Directory` have a `getSize()` method? It could just call `getSize()` on all its children and add up the results.

You have a `writable` attribute on your objects, but you don't seem to be using it, e.g. in `setName()` you just replace the name of the object without checking if it's writable. Similarly, you have a `parent` argument in the constructor, but you don't use it; I'd expect the `File` to call `addContent()` on its parent automatically if the parent is specified in the constructor.

As for further features, I'd recommend making your `Directory` class iterable (so it can be used in `for` loops), as well as implementing the most common collection methods, such as `forEach`, `has`, `length` (i.e. the number of files in the directory), etc., instead of just exposing the array of children.